# How to get initial PaginationToken on AWS Cognito list users in aws sdk js

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-cognito

I am trying to list the matching users from cognito userpool using expressJs api to check if the username already exists or not.
Code:

```
listUserFromUserpool = async () => {
var params = {
  UserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID /* required */,
  AttributesToGet: ["username"],
  Filter: 'username = "example"',
  Limit: 5,
  PaginationToken: "What to pass here initially ?",
};

try {
  let data = await this.cognitoIdentity.listUsers(params).promise();
  return data;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return false;
}
};
```

But getting error in `PaginationToken` . What should i insert into the `PaginationToken` param initially as I get the `PaginationToken` in the next response?

Or, is there any way to get single user without using pagination?